# Adding items to list while avoiding redundant items

Tags: ruby

I am a student. I am not just looking for an answer; I care about the logic.

The `add_item!` method should take two arguments. The first argument is the item you want to add to the list and the second argument is the array (i.e. list) to which the item will be added. The method should not add duplicates. For example, you could start with this:

```
def add_item!(item, list)
end
```

If we were simply shoveling items into the list, without worrying about duplicates, we could write:

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item
  list # this is what we return from the method
end
```

We're naming the method with a bang because it modifies the list passed in. If we didn't want to modify that list--and wanted to instead return a different list with the new item--what could we do?

The tricky part is adding the logic to ensure that we're not adding the same item twice. There's a method in Ruby's Array class that will be helpful here: it's called `include?`, takes an argument, and returns `true` or `false`. For example:

```
[1,2,3].include?(3) #=> true
[1,2,3].include?(4) #=> false
```

Try to use the `include?` method to determine if the given item is in the given list and complete the `add_item!` implementation.

My attempt is such:

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  if list.include?(item)
    list.delete(item)
  else  
    list << item
    list # this is what we return from the method
  end
end

p add_item!("banana", ["orange"])
p add_item!("orange", ["orange"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the answer: you don't need to call delete because this will delete the existing element in the list. If list.include? return false, just add it to the list, if true, do nothing...

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  if !list.include?(item)
    list << item
  end
  list # this is what we return from the method
end
```

Comment: The OP said he didnt want a solution. He wants to know what he is doing wrong. Thats why I didn't give him the solution. :)

Comment: LOL... That's Ok... I was still able to get the logic "tomsoft" provided and this relieved my brain aneurysm immensely!  Thank you both Santosh and tomsoft!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong:

If the Array contains the item, it will be deleted and else part will **NOT** be executed. So the item will **NOT** get inserted and the method returns the return value of the last statement, which is `list.delete(item)`.

According to [Array#delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-delete),

> Deletes all items from self that are equal to obj.
>
> Returns the last deleted item, or nil if no matching item is found.